# Formik arrayHelpers remove is not removing the selected item

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using Formik's arrayHelpers to push and remove objects from an array of objects. The push works as expected and adds the object and its values to the array. The remove works when you only select one item in the array and then deselect it. The problem, however starts when you select multiple items. For instance, you select the first item and it is added to the array and then select the second item and it is added to the array, but say you want to deselect that second item and you click on it, the first item is deselected. Then if you click on it again, it deselects the second item.

```
initialValue: lenders: []

/*mock array of lenders*/
const lenders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Lender1',
    value: 'Lender1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Lender2',
    value: 'Lender2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'Lender3',
    value: 'Lender3',
  },
]
<FieldArray
  name="lenders"
  render={arrayHelpers => (
    <div className="lenders">
      {lenders.map(lender => (
        <div key={lender.id}>
          <Field name={`lender${lender.id}`}>
            {({ field, meta }) => (
              <SelectableCard
                id={field.name}
                name={field.name}
                text={lender.value}
                isSelected={props.values.lenders.some(
                  len => len.id === lender.id
                )}
                label={lender.value}
                inputName={field.name}
                value={lender.value}
                ref={field.ref}
                onClick={evt => {
                 let isSelected = props.values.lenders.some(
                   len => len.id === lender.id
                 );
                 isSelected
                  ? arrayHelpers.remove(lender)
                  : arrayHelpers.push({
                      id: lender.id,
                      value: lender.value,
                  });

                  field.onChange({
                   target: {
                    id: lender.id,
                    value: !isSelected,
                   },
                  });
                 }}
              />
            )}
          </Field>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 4):

This was solved by changing the isSelected const in the onClick to finding the index like this:

```
const index = props.values.lenders.findIndex(
      len => len.id === lender.id
);
```

Then wrapping the arrayHelpers to check if the index is greater than -1:

```
index > -1
      ? arrayHelpers.remove(index)
      : arrayHelpers.push({
          id: lender.id,
          value: lender.value,
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

FieldArray's `arrayHelpers` render props takes an index of the item to be removed and not the object to be removed

Pass on the index that you obtain from map

```
<FieldArray
  name="lenders"
  render={arrayHelpers => (
    <div className="lenders">
      {lenders.map((lender, index) => (
        <div key={lender.id}>
          <Field name={`lender${lender.id}`}>
            {({ field, meta }) => (
              <SelectableCard
                id={field.name}
                name={field.name}
                text={lender.value}
                isSelected={props.values.lenders.some(
                  len => len.id === lender.id
                )}
                label={lender.value}
                inputName={field.name}
                value={lender.value}
                ref={field.ref}
                onClick={evt => {
                 let isSelected = props.values.lenders.some(
                   len => len.id === lender.id
                 );
                 isSelected
                  ? arrayHelpers.remove(index)
                  : arrayHelpers.push({
                      id: lender.id,
                      value: lender.value,
                  });

                  field.onChange({
                   target: {
                    id: lender.id,
                    value: !isSelected,
                   },
                  });
                 }}
              />
            )}
          </Field>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just gave that a shot and it works initially but after selecting and deselecting a few options it starts having odd behavior of not removing the item when you click on it but when you click on another item it will remove it.

Comment: I don't hink you need the field.onChange in this case if you are using arrayHelpers

Comment: Sorry about just now responding. I did remove the onChange and still no luck. I noticed on the documentation that you are supposed to follow an object.index.property convention. Do I need to add something to the arrayHelpers.push to account for that?

Comment: I think you need to define "key" in <SelectableCard key="some-unique-value">. React use "key" to determine component in array. In short key make it possible to do operation to the correct child component.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you should remove the index of the item/object not the object itself.
I encountered this while integrating Formik with ChipInput and solved as follows:

```
 <FieldArray
                    name="topics"
                    render={arrayHelpers => (
                      <Field
                        name="topics"
                        component={ChipInput}
                        type="text"
                        label="Topics"
                        value={values.topics}
                        margin="none"
                        onAdd={chip => arrayHelpers.push(chip)}
                        onDelete={chip =>
                          arrayHelpers.remove(values.topics.indexOf(chip))
                        }
                        fullWidth
                        chipRenderer={chipRenderer}
                        helperText={errors.topics ? errors.topics : ''}
                        error={errors.topics ? true : false}
                      />
```

Comment: Definitely. That ended up solving it. After thinking about it for a little while I realized I was thinking about it wrong. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: not working for me, event after passing index to the remove method, it removes last index